# images are not properly displaying in viewpager(Continiousely changing its position )

Tags: android

I am doing code for showing server side images in a viewpager.

But as per my code all images are loaded successfully but problem is that image position is not constant. I mean position of images are continuously changing after swipe.

Please solve my problem.

Custom_swipe_adapter.java

```
 public class Custom_swipe_adapter extends PagerAdapter {
private String[] img;
private Context ctx;
Bitmap[] bitmap;
ImageView imgofer;
Bitmap b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public Custom_swipe_adapter(Context ctx,String [] img)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
    this.img=img;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return img.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view ==(LinearLayout)object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemview=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
    bitmap=new Bitmap[img.length];
    imgofer= (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.swipeimg);
    Log.v("abhi", img[position]);


    ImageView i1=imgofer;
    if (imgofer != null) {
        new ImageDownloaderTask(i1).execute(img[position]);

    }

    imgofer.setImageBitmap(b1);

    container.addView(itemview);
    Log.v("TAG", "aaaaaaaaaaaa"+img[position]);
    return itemview;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
}

class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(params[0]).getContent());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        b1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b1, 270, 375, true);
        return b1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(b1);
                } else {
                    Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loadingoffer);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }
            }

        }
    }


}


 }
```

My Image View:

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/swipeimg"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/loadingoffer" />
```

My View Pager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/slideimg"> </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your XML file, go to your ImageView and try to play with its scaleType.

I think that `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` may work for you.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for additional information.

> *P.S. The format of your question is really bad.*

Comment: sorry for format but i am new to android so please help me

Comment: my images are not shown properly.means it automatically changes it position and load all images at all positions

Comment: Can you post also your xml file including your ImageView. And also add screenshots maybe. What do you mean by not proper?

Comment: You may use an image downloader library for resizing, caching and queueing images. Check them out:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/swipeimg"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loadingoffer" />

Comment: <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/slideimg">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>